# Maximum Document Id

Tags: ravendb

If I insert a `User` into the `Users` collection and it's the first document RavenDB might assign it an id of `users/1`.

If the id field is a string and the [maximum length of the id field is 1023](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document), what is the limit on how far these automatically assigned ids can grow?  Is there an upper limit like maxint?  i.e. `users/2147483647`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numeric is is a long.  That gives you 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 distinct ids.

Comment: Thank you... that'll probably be enough :-)

Comment: Woooohoo. That will look nice in my edit view `/Edit/User/9223372036854775807`